# How is this $2rθ$ even supposed to describe an arc of a circle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, geometry

It's my understanding that theta (θ) is always calculated in degrees. Can someone clarify for me how the equation 2=rθ describes the arc of a circle? I am trying to formulate an expression for time as a particle moves from one point to another on a circular path.

Comment: theta will be in radians, and then the firmula for the arc of a circle is r times theta (theta is 2 pi for the full circle)

Comment: Presumably $\theta = \omega t$ so for constant $r$ the particle is moving around a circle with angular velocity $2\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

The arc length of a circle is

$$s= 2\pi r$$

The arc length of a sector of a circle, as a function of angle, is therefore

$$s= (\frac{\theta}{360 })2\pi r$$

However angles are more commonly measured in radians.

There are $2\pi$ radians in a full circle so  this instead becomes

$$s= (\frac{\theta}{2\pi })2\pi r$$

$$s = r\theta$$

Now this doesn't really do much in determining the path a object moves on in a circular path

definining a circular vector path would be
$$\vec{R}(t) = r \cos(\theta)\hat i + r\sin(\theta) \hat j $$

Where $\theta = \omega t$

This comes from standard trigonometry, but the adjacent and opposite sides are displayed as vectors

Factoring r we can also use polar vectors

$$R(t) = r \hat r$$

Answer (score 1):

Answering to the first sentence in your edited question: no, angles aren't given in degree.

I always say to my students that, ideally, they should forget that degrees exist and always work in radian. Two very simple examples showing why, taken from basic math where units aren't used anyway.

1. The length of an arc circle of angle $\theta$ and radius $R$ is $R\theta$. You know that the perimeter of a circle is $2\pi R$. The latter is derived from the former with $\theta=2\pi$, which is valid only in radian.
2. The Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ to first order is $\sin(x)=x+o(x)$. You can check numerically that this doesn't work in degree.

The idea is that angle is a dimensionless quantity, so it shouldn't have any unit. It's only for historical reasons, because degrees existed and were in wide use, that the "real" value of an angle was given a unit (radian).

As a consequence, I also say to my students that there are only a few situations where they should use angles in degrees:

- to communicate with non-scientists
- where they're using a measuring device that is build with degrees, like a goniometer

Answer (score -2):

S = rƟ is actually the arc-length formula *in radians*, so this automatically takes care of the units on your theta.

That being said, as with all my answers, I always ask the OP to take it back to their basic definitions. S is for position; r is the radius; θ is the subtended angle also in radians because of your position vector.

This equation is used in fluid dynamics in finding the wetted portion of a circular pipe with a specific depth to the water, but also has applications in other branches of physics. Since you're wanting to write an equation in terms of *time*, you can differentiate your position and acceleration vector equations with respect to that *change* in time (Δt) as it changes positions on the arc, but in relation to uniform circular motion, which is from where your derivation equations hail.

That may not be a complete-enough answer, so if not, let me know.

Cheers.